# Print Random Values from an 2D Array, these values coming from other 1D arrays (should be strings)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a 2D array with 500 rows of random string values but each columns must have each own random values like, the first column will have only "M" or "F", then the second one must only have "Bsc" or "Msc" and so on. In total it will have 4 columns, Gender, Program, Studies and Year.

After this I will need to print out all possible values from this 2D array.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class read {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row = 500;
        int col = 5;
        String[][] grid = new String[row][col];
        String[] Gj = {"M","F"};
        String[] AB = Gj;
        SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(row);
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
                sb.toString();
                grid[i][j] = sb.toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(""+grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

This is what I have done up to now, I know there's a problem with using AB.length() over there.

Comment: Also add your expected output.

Comment: What is the point of your StringBuilder here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. I have done for column 1 & 2.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int row = 500;
    int col = 5;
    String[][] grid = new String[row][col];
    String[] col1 = {"M","F"};
    String[] col2 = {"Bsc","Msc"};
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            if(j == 0) {
                grid[i][j] = col1[rnd.nextInt(col1.length)];
            } else if(j == 1) {
                grid[i][j] = col2[rnd.nextInt(col2.length)];
            } else if(j == 2) {
                grid[i][j] = "studies"+rnd.nextInt();
            } else {
                grid[i][j] = "year"+rnd.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```